# Read JSON Data Using PHP

Tags: php, json, solr

Solr returns response in following JSON format.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "indent":"on",
      "start":"0",
      "q":"*:*",
      "wt":"json",
      "version":"2.2",
      "rows":"10"}},
  "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "student_id":"AB1001",
        "student_name":[
          "John"]
    },
      {
        "student_id":"AB1002",
        "student_name":[
          "Joe"]
    },
      {
        "student_id":"AB1003",
        "student_name":[
          "Lorem"]
    }]

  }}
```

What will be the simple way to read student_id, student_name using PHP?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. There's a `]` missing before the final `}}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `$obj = json_decode($yourJSONString);` to convert it to an object.

Then use `foreach($obj->response->docs as $doc)` to iterate over the "docs".

You can then access the fields using `$doc->student_id` and `$doc->student_name[0]`.

Answer (score 10):

PHP has a json_decode function that will allow you to turn a JSON string into an array:

```
$array = json_decode($json_string, true);
$student_id = $array['response']['docs'][0]['student_id'];
...
```

Of course, you might want to iterate through the list of students instead of accessing index 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = json_decode($result, true);
$result['response']['docs'][0]['student_id'] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use one of the PHP clients for Solr, or the PHP response writer? See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_a = json_decode($string, TRUE);
$json_o = json_decode($string);


#array method
foreach($json_a['response']['docs'] as $students)
{
    echo $students['student_id']." name is ".$students['student_name'][0];
    echo "<br>";
}

#Object Method`enter code here`
foreach($json_o->response->docs as $sthudent_o)
{
    echo $sthudent_o->student_id. " name is ".$sthudent_o->student_name[0];
    echo "<br>";
}
```